# Remove rows with a specific cell color - CONDITIONAL FORMAT COLOR

Tags: vba, excel, colors

Rule 1: Delete Row IF cells in column A are Green AND Column J contains the term "SA Comments -" just contains not exact THEN delete row.
 Then Rule 2: Delete Row IF cells in column A are Red AND Column J DOES NOT contain the term "SA Comments -" THEN delete row.
 Then Rule 3: IF a cell in column J has no value THEN Add the term "Sa Comments -" to any cell that has no value.

These cells are filled red with conditional formatting?

I understand I need to user Instr? If am not looking for an exact match.

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Cell_Color()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long

lRow = 9999
For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And Cells(iCntr, 10).Value = "SA Comments -" Then
    '2 = None
    Rows(iCntr).Delete

    ElseIf Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 And Cells(iCntr, 10).Value <> "SA Comments -" Then
        '4 = Red
        Rows(iCntr).Delete
    End If

Next iCntr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me, just make sure you are having `Interior.Color` of 4 in the cells in Column A.

Not sure, but you are looking to have an exact match or partial match of "SA Comments -" ?

Are you looking for text in Column J while checking the interior color in Column A ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim lastrow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Outstanding Aged Incidents")
    ' reading last row with data from Column A
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1            
        If .Cells(i, 10).Value = "SA Comments -" And .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = 4 Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If        
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

---

**Edit 1**: If you are looking for partial match of "SA Comments -" , you have 2 alternatives:

***Instr*** - use the line below:

```
If InStr(.Cells(iCntr, 10).Value, "SA Comments -") > 0 Then
```

***Like*** - use the line below:

```
If .Cells(iCntr, 10).Value Like "*SA Comments -*" Then
```

**Edit 2**: Modified code to suit the code uploaded by PO since original post.

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Cell_Color()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long

lRow = 9999
For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And InStr(Cells(iCntr, 10).Value, "SA Comments -") > 0 Then
    '2 = None
    Rows(iCntr).Delete

    ElseIf Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 And InStr(Cells(iCntr, 10).Value, "SA Comments -") > 0 Then
        '4 = Red
        Rows(iCntr).Delete
    End If

Next iCntr

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm not looking for an exact match. Currently looking for that solution now. I have the following code below at the moment.





















Sub sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Cell_Color()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lRow = 9999
For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
If Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And InStr(1, cel.Value, "SA Comments -") Then
‘2 = None
Rows(iCntr).Delete


ElseIf Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 And Cells(iCntr, 10).Value <> "SA Comments -" Then
‘4 = Red
Rows(iCntr).Delete
End If

Next
End Sub

Comment: Hi there, I got invalid or unqualified ref?

Comment: you are trying to use all my code ? or partial ? because you changed your code from your original post

Comment: Partial sorry, I've added the new code which I'm working on above

Comment: @D.Mitchell try code under **Edit 2** (copy the entire section)

Comment: Hi there, Will this pick up the conditional format of the color red?

Comment: Haven't tested that , did it ?

Comment: I don't know, because it seems to delete everything with SA Comments in the column. Using the code Below.











Sub sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Cell_Color()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long

lRow = 9999
For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone And InStr(Cells(iCntr, 10).Value, "SA Comments") > 0 Then
    '2 = None
    Rows(iCntr).Delete

    ElseIf Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 And Cells(iCntr, 10).Value = "SA Comments" Then
        '3 = Red
        Rows(iCntr).Delete
    End If

Next iCntr

End Sub

Comment: After these two ruels are complete, I would then like to add "D" to all cells with no values in column 10

Comment: I see what the problem is here, its not picking up the conditional formatting. So if the conditional formatting is there as red it wont pick it up, it'll just think its blank haha :)